# Module numpy have no attribute in the command disp=lib.disloc3d3 commands

Tags: attributes

```
disp = lib.disloc3d3(xx_vec, yy_vec, xoff=xcen, yoff=ycen, depth=centroid_depth,
                  length=length, width=width, slip=slip, opening=0, 
                   strike=strike, dip=dip, rake=rake, nu=0.25)
```

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[35], line 19
16 model = [xcen, ycen, strike, dip, rake, slip, length, centroid_depth, width]
18 # Calculate displacements
---> 19 disp = lib.disloc3d3(xx_vec, yy_vec, xoff=xcen, yoff=ycen, depth=centroid_depth,
20                   length=length, width=width, slip=slip, opening=0,
21                    strike=strike, dip=dip, rake=rake, nu=0.25)
23 # Plot the three components of displacement
24 lib.plot_enu(disp, model, x, y)

File ~/coseis_lib.py:59, in disloc3d3(x, y, xoff, yoff, depth, length, width, slip, opening, strike, dip, rake, nu)
57 # check that top of fault isn't above 0 m surface
58 top_depth = depth - (width/2) * np.sin(np.deg2rad(dip))
---> 59 assert top_depth >= np.float(0), "Fault breaches 0 m surface, please change either centroid depth or fault width."
61 x = x - xoff
62 y = y - yoff

File /opt/conda/envs/anaconda-panel-2023.05-py310/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/**init**.py:305, in **getattr**(attr)
300     warnings.warn(
301         f"In the future `np.{attr}` will be defined as the "
302         "corresponding NumPy scalar.", FutureWarning, stacklevel=2)
304 if attr in **former_attrs**:
--> 305     raise AttributeError(**former_attrs**[attr])
307 # Importing Tester requires importing all of UnitTest which is not a
308 # cheap import Since it is mainly used in test suits, we lazy import it
309 # here to save on the order of 10 ms of import time for most users
310 #
311 # The previous way Tester was imported also had a side effect of adding
312 # the full `numpy.testing` namespace
313 if attr == 'testing':

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'.
`np.float` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `float` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations